# Flutter Getx How to navigate to other page in StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-getx

I am using firebase_auth to signup and login.
I am facing a problem with Streambuilder.

I would like to show page depends on User Logged in or not. It seems working fine.
But, the problem is that I can't use Get.off('/app'); in StreamBuilder and FutureBuilder.
if I can't use Getx.off('/app'); user can get back just pressing the back button, and
I would like to avoid this, so I am trying to use Get.off page route.

But, as vs code shows that FutureBuilder and StreamBuilder's builder return Widget,
and I have no idea how to code.

Any suggestion for this matter?

```
    // main.dart
    void main() async {
      WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return GetMaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Karrot Market Clone',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: Colors.black,
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
            visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
            appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
          initialBinding: InitBinding(),
          initialRoute: '/',
          getPages: [
            GetPage(
              name: '/',
              page: () => BridgeFirebase(),
            ),
            GetPage(
              name: '/bridge_page',
              page: () => BridgePage(),
            ),
            GetPage(
              name: '/app',
              page: () => App(),
              transition: Transition.rightToLeft,
            ),
            GetPage(
              name: '/start',
              page: () => Start(),
            ),
            GetPage(
              name: '/login',
              page: () => Login(),
              transition: Transition.rightToLeft,
            ),
            GetPage(
              name: '/signup',
              page: () => SignUp(),
              transition: Transition.rightToLeft,
            ),
          ],
        );
      }
    }
```

```
      class BridgeFirebase extends StatelessWidget {
      const BridgeFirebase({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: Firebase.initializeApp(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text('Firebase load fail'));
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return BridgePage();
            }
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                color: ColorsKM.primary,
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

```
    class BridgePage extends StatelessWidget {
      const BridgePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<User?> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Splash();
            }
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return App();
            } else {
              return Start();
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

```
// app.dart
class App extends GetView<AppController> {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget _bodyWidget() {
    switch (RouteName.values[controller.currentIndex.value]) {
      case RouteName.HOME:
        return Home();
        break;
      case RouteName.MYLOCAL:
        return MyLocal();
        break;
      case RouteName.NEARBY:
        return Nearby();
        break;
      case RouteName.CHATS:
        return Chats();
        break;
      case RouteName.MYKARROT:
        return MyKarrot();
        break;
    }
    return Container();
  }

  BottomNavigationBarItem _bottomNavigationBarItem(
      String iconName, String label) {
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
        child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/${iconName}_off.svg', width: 22),
      ),
      activeIcon: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0),
        child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/${iconName}_on.svg', width: 22),
      ),
      label: label,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Obx(
        () {
          return _bodyWidget();
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Obx(
        () => BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          currentIndex: controller.currentIndex.value,
          selectedFontSize: 12.0,
          showSelectedLabels: true,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          selectedLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          onTap: controller.changePageIndex,
          items: [
            _bottomNavigationBarItem('home', 'home'),
            _bottomNavigationBarItem('notes', 'neighbor'),
            _bottomNavigationBarItem('location', 'nearby'),
            _bottomNavigationBarItem('chat', 'chat'),
            _bottomNavigationBarItem('user', 'my karrot'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
// app_controller.dart
enum RouteName {
  HOME,
  MYLOCAL,
  NEARBY,
  CHATS,
  MYKARROT,
}

class AppController extends GetxService {
  static AppController get to => Get.find();

  late RxInt currentIndex = 0.obs;

  void changePageIndex(int index) {
    currentIndex(index);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the build method is not completed when you navigate in Streambuilder so you can delay some time to the build method complete then navigate. do this when you want to navigate in Streambuilder :

```
Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) => Get.off('/app'));
```

or just navigate in your controller or bloc class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't understand what you mean. Do you mean that I should return 'return Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((value) => Get.off('/app'));' instead of return App()? I tried it and I got an error 'The return type 'Future<Future<dynamic>?>' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.'.
Could you please more specify your answer? Forgive me for my lack of knowledge 

Comment: No, everywhere that you want to use navigate in build method, use it inside Future.delayed , you should not return this in build method

Comment: In my code, I used StreamBuilder and each if statement has return Widget. I think that I should use StreamBuilder to route pages depends on snapshot has data or not. Do you mean that there is another way that I can implement what I want to do as same as returning Widget directly? Could you give me some more details or code examples?

Comment: Where do you navigate?? provide me some code

Comment: I added app.dart and app_controller.dart codes. I would like to navigate to App class View with Get.off navigate when user login.

Comment: I just figured it out temporarily adding OnWillPopScope(onWillPop: () async => false) Widget and wrap Scaffold Widget of App class view. Once I logged in back button is disabled. It wasn't the way I wanted, but for now, it is fine to me as it works okay. Thank you for your help, Mojtaba Ghiasi 